# Hey folks, can anybody help me by pointing out some of the best multisig solutions on Ethereum? Urgent, and much appreciated

Tags: multisignature

1. What are some of the best multisig solutions on Ethereum?
2. What are some of the best practices?
3. Any notable and interesting projects I should know about?

Comment: I generally use [Gnosis Safe](https://gnosis-safe.io/) for multisig wallet, especially for the use case where we need something like 2 out of 3 signers to transact.

Comment: Hey Turboza, thanks for the reply. Apart from Gnosis Safe, are there any other options that come to your mind?

Comment: I don't find any clearly safe & decentralized solutions other than Gnosis Safe for Ethereum-based chain yet, hopefully someone else could share more. For other chains, you can see [here](https://alphasec.io/what-is-a-multisig-wallet/). And note that multisig wallet does not come risk-free, they can introduce new risks. See more about [OP token hacked](https://cryptonews.com/news/wintermutes-amateur-mistake-leads-loss-of-20m-optimism-tokens.htm).